# In the finite difference formulas, how can we pick h to give a certain tolerance?

Tags: inequality, derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

There's lots of questions on here about finite differences. In particular, picking the 'best' h value. But what if I want to find the biggest 'h' which bounds to a given tolerance?

On first glance, I would think for a simple two-point forward difference:

$$ f(x+h) - f(x)\over h\\  $$

That the inequality could simply be:

$$ -h/2 \times f''(c) > some-tolerance $$

In this case, my function is simply $$ sin(2x) $$

However, it could easily be any function.

However, after some working out it seems to depend on $c$... which depends on $h$. Where should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second derivative is bounded on the interval you want, just use its maximum.

Comment: Well, see the dilemma is... what IS my interval? Clearly, it starts at x but then c stretches out as far as 'h' can go.

Comment: For the trig functions, it's obvious that "1" is a good maximum. However, what about the rest?

Comment: You have the option of bounding $h$, say, assuming $h \leq 1$ and going from there. Otherwise, you can look at the second derivative near $x$ and see how big its getting. The maximum can only increase over a larger interval.

Comment: So you're telling me basically I can't find the 'smallest' h easily, right? Only a 'good' h given some bounds I decide?

Comment: Finding the absolute smallest $h$ is about as hard as explicitly evaluating the derivative. Getting a merely "good" $h$ is easier.